# Error when trying to publish map on QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-cloud, qgis-3

So when I try to publish a map with plugin " QGIS Cloud " I get this error which you can see on picture down below, anyone have solutions how to fix it? 
P.S. I am using QGIS 3.4

[image]

UPDATE After trying 1st SOLUTION i get this error :

[image]

Last error i get is this one :

[image]

It happens after some time after processing Upload Data to QGIS Cloud

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, you seem to have a raster file in your project (*.tif, *.jpg, ...)

To solve the issue you need to remove the layer and check if there are still layers in the *Upload Data* tab of the plugin.

Comment: So after deleting all of them I got this Python Error : " TypeError: writeXml() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given "

Comment: please check above, I posted a new picture.

Comment: @Roby5 The new error suggests, that not all layers were uploaded to QGISCloud. Did you check on the Uploading data tab?

Comment: Yeah it says everything is uploaded hmm